Op-amp (LM348N) becomes very hot when connected to power
Is it normal for an op-amp to become very hot immediately when I connect its power pins? Nothing else is connected yet, just +5 V to the VCC+ and GND to VCC- pins.
I never used an op-amp before, just experimenting with it. Maybe the chip is faulty, but now I have no more pieces to try.

How did you connect the supply pins?

No, it's not normal for an op-amp to become hot with power connected but all other pins floating.
I've used boards with one op-amp input going straight to a connector and they were fine. And I, and I'm sure a mass of learners out there, have plugged op-amps into breadboards with inputs floating, powered them on through long wires to a supply and had them sitting quiet and cold.
It's pretty much that you've either (a) got an op-amp that was already faulty, (b) have damaged it in handling or (c) connected the power supply polarity backwards.
It is very, very unlikely that powering it with all other pins floating caused it to overheat.

With unconnected/floating inputs and without bypass caps, anything is normal. It's not supposed to be used like that. It might have been damaged under these usage conditions. Or it is just oscillating wildly and is undamaged. Or, it might be heating due to the issues you mentioned (already faulty, damaged by handling, or power applied imvorrectly to wrong pins or with wrong polarity). Although it may not be a good idea to power the opamp with 5V single supply if recommended conditions say minimum +/- 4V dual supply.

@Justme, of course "anything" isn't normal and you're just open-endedly speculating that anything is possible. Build 'n'000 units and you can start to measure what normal actually is. My practical engineering experience is that the normal case is: op-amps well and truly don't do that. No decoupling capacitors really won't be a problem. Maybe you're reading the question as "is it possible?", not as "is it normal?" which it asks. Engineering is looking at real-world cases with actual ICs, can't just scale up datasheet info into "every what-if is possible".

No, sorry, I was not the downvoter. I would also not expect a 7805 regulator to turn into an oscillator either as they normally don't do that. But with long input leads and without a bypass cap on input, out of a batch of maybe few tens of units, a couple of them did, as conditions were just right for it to happen, like stray capacitances and feedback bandwidth. ICs can have have large manufacturing tolerances while still being in spec with datasheet parameters.

@Justme, equally, sorry I wrote such a firm rebuttal and thanks for your sincerity :-) As electronics engineers, we deal with electronics (a pure subject and science) and engineering (practical application of it in the real world). The notion that it's normal for an op-amp isn't borne out in my engineering experience, not by a long chalk. (Looking at Q/A's here now, imagine the Q was instead on ESD damage in, say, an FPGA. Does a data sheet warn about it: yes, sternly. What's it like it practice: you can get away with murder with them. Is static damage normal: no. Is it possible: very yes.)

@Justme: Unless switching extreme inductive or capacitive loads, devices which go into weird oscillating modes won't generally dissipate so much excess power as a result that they go from "not even warm" to "noticeably hot".  A device which is specified to have a static (steady-state) current of 10uA might draw 100 times that amount as a result of a floating input, which might be an absolute disaster if the device is powered by a 2016 cell, but wouldn't affect the temperature of the device.

Yes. Don't leave your inputs floating - first chapter in every datasheet. The high input impedance of the pins act as little antennas and cause the chips to oscillate creating heat. Create a resistor divider (Vcc/2) and tie all the non-inverting inputs (IN+) to the middle of this voltage divider. Connect each amplifier output to its respective inverting input (IN-). For reference, these are called voltage follows or voltage buffers and bias the amplifiers to a "calm" state of operation. Your second order problem is you have to decouple the  chip - put a 0.1uF capacitor and maybe a 1uF capacitor across your chip Vcc and Gnd pins. Depending on your power supply and leads powering the chip, this, too, may cause oscillations for similar reasons as leaving the inputs floating also creating waste heat from the internal transistors popping in and out of saturation.
Unused amplifiers should look like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

While fine for an LM348 (at least as fine as it can be, considering you're using one of the worst op amps still on the market), note that this is not always what you want to do. Some op amps are optimized for high-bandwidth operation in a way that makes them unstable at low gain (such as a gain of 1 as you have here); these are called "decompensated" op amps. The datasheet will be pretty clear when this is what you have--it's not a normal feature for op amps to have.

@Hearth I understand that, but I checked the LM348 and it is unity-gain stable so it's internally compensated which usually means its compensated with a dominant-pole at origin. I wanted to give Denatural, an individual  "who never used an op-amp before", a starting point without complicating things.

Point #1
First check that you have correctly connected the power supply to the opamp - getting this wrong will cause major problems, including over-heating. It's a good idea to use a power supply with a current limit.
In this case, start with setting the current limit to, say, 10mA, and go from there.
Also put a capacitor (about 100nF = 0.1uF) across the power supply pins of the opamp.  This capacitor should be physically located as close as possible to the opamp, & connected to the opamp pins with short tracks/wires.
Point #2
Never leave inputs of opamps unconnected, as this can lead to high frequency oscillation which can lead to over heating. Same rule applies to logic gates.
The simplest way to achieve this is to configure the opamp as a voltage follower (output connected to its negative input), and its positive input connected to gnd.  However, some opamps are not stable in this configuration and may still oscillate, so check the datasheet to confirm it is indeed stable in this configuration (look for terms such as "unity gain stable").
The good news is that the opamp you have, the LM348N, is unity gain stable and the datasheet from Texas Instruments shows it connected in the unity-gain (or "voltage follower") configuration, refer screen shot below, Figure 1.


Thank you very much for your answers, I learned a lot from them! But it turns out that I had accidentally caused the problem.
I hadn't realised that I had plugged the banana plugs into the power supply the wrong way, I had just blindly trusted the usual polarity of the red and black cables.
As soon as I reversed the polarity, the opamp didn't heat up at all, even when only the power leads were plugged in.
